# How to properly manage dependencies amongst modules in an Xcode project/workspace?

Tags: swift, xcode, clean-architecture

I’m trying to modularize my app and structure the code by layers - Data, Domain, Application and Shared. My aim is to have the modules totally independent of one another with strict dependency rules.   
I’ve started with making a workspace with separate projects but in a workspace all projects have unlimited access to each other’s targets, files and products and there’s no way I can limit that (as pointed here - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-multiple-projects-and-their-dependencies)

The second approach was to use the Swift Package Manager and make a separate package for every layer, other than the Application layer, configure the dependencies between them (Data -> Domain, Data -> Shared) and then bring them to the main project as dependencies. The problem here is that even though every layer has its own dependencies, they bleed out and are accessible from the referencing project.
As an example, if I reference Alamofire in the Data project, and then add the Data project as a dependency to the Application project then the Alamofire package is accessible in the Application project (even though it is not needed there, it has nothing to do in the Application layer, it has just became available by having the Data project as a dependency). This is expected when working with SPM as described here - https://forums.swift.org/t/preventing-spm-packages-dependencies-from-being-exported-when-importing-the-package/43660

How can I properly isolate all the layers without having access to implementation details when importing them?

Thank you!